# ¿Es correcto dar una solución que involucre cambiar toda la estructura del código?

Tags: discusión

Hago esta pregunta con el fin de informarme (si alguien la responde). Me he topado con preguntas en las cuales se plantea el problema con un intento de código, en esas mismas pregunta la persona que la responde da una solución al problema, pero totalmente diferente por donde se estaba yendo. Tipo que da su propia solución, y ni siquiera explica por que hizo esos cambios. Estos cambios son muy bruscos, cosas como implementar funciones y  definir nuevas variables. Esas respuesta las leo y pienso más bien que le están haciendo el trabajo al OP y no están respondiendo al problema planteado. Un ejemplo:

> **La pregunta:** Cuál es la manera correcta de usar X método de X librería. Da un contexto de cuál es su propósito final.

> **La respuesta:** Implementé esto y esto, te tiene que funcionar.

No sé si me expliqué bien, pero está respuesta no responden a la duda en especifico, si no se enfocan en cumplir el propósito del OP.

Resumiendo: **¿Que tan adecuadas son este tipo de respuestas, son adecuadas?**

Gracias por leer, xD.

Comment: He aqui un ejemplo de una respuesta correcta, adecuada y útil que involucra un cambio total de enfoque: [Cómo muestro secciones de una lista] (https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/372391/c%c3%b3mo-muestro-secciones-de-una-listapython)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Contesta a la pregunta tal y como la plantea el usuario**. En todo caso, **comenta si el código que muestra el OP está hecho así por algún motivo**.

No olvidemos que el código que acompaña a la pregunta **ha de ser un Ejemplo Mínimo Verificable**; No necesariamente ha de ser el código real que el usuario está usando, y es posible que durante el proceso de *destilado*, por intentar condensarlo al mínimo, el código no tenga mucho sentido. O las explicaciones no concuerden con el código. O lo que se hace sea algo ilógico ... **fuera de su contexto real**.

Reescribir el código del OP sin tener en cuenta esto, a mi juicio es una falta de respeto hacia el usuario.

Esto no es una regla absoluta; hay preguntas en las que claramente el usuario lo está haciendo mal porque, como dicen en mi tierra, *está mas perdido que un sapo en el desierto*. Pero afortunadamente, el sitio permite dejar comentarios.

¡ Usemoslos ! Comentemos, pidamos explicaciones, y, con las ideas claras, respondamos a la pregunta.

Answer (score 6):

Lo primero a tener presente es que no todas las preguntas se pueden ni se deben de responder. Ref. [¿Cómo escribo una buena respuesta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Lo segundo es que la respuesta debe responder la pregunta. Por ejemplo, si la pregunta es sobre `Array` en *JavaScript* y la el código usa `Sets` sin explicar el motivo, por más maravilloso que sea el código este no está respondiendo la pregunta.

En el caso particular que pones como ejemplo, no es del todo afortunado porque sin tener mayores detalles no podemos saber si es en realidad una buena pregunta y no una basada en opiniones. Entonces, volviendo al premisa inicial, la respuesta debe responder la pregunta, pero si no se puede o no se debe responder, no importa lo que diga la respuesta ya que lo que procede es, si se puede, mejorar la pregunta, y si no se puede, cerrarla.

Comment: Gracias por responder! Otra pregunta, qué debo hacer cuando encuentro una respuesta que no responde a una pregunta?

Comment: Asumiendo que sí es un intento por responder, podrías dejar un comentario dejando una sugerencia de cómo mejorar la respuesta y/o podrías votar negativo. Si no intenta responder la pregunta, lo que procede es reportarla.

Comment: Entendido, gracias!

Answer (score 4):

Veamos este ejemplo, totalmente ficticio, pero es el tipo de preguntas que se encuentran por acá:

**Pregunta:** ¿Cómo aumento el tamaño de la memoria en Python?

**Cuerpo:**
Tengo que evaluar una función en 1000 puntos y calcular el promedio, pero se me cae por un error de memoria. ¿Cómo hago para aumentar la RAM de Python?

Este es mi programa:

```
def suma_lista(lista):
    if len(lista) == 1:
        return lista[0]
    else:
        return lista[0] + suma_lista(lista[1:])

valores = []
for i in range(1000):
    valores.append(some_function(i))

promedio = suma_lista(valores) / len(valores)
```

y este es el error (está en inglés, no lo entiendo mucho):

```
  File "/home/jsilva/.config/JetBrains/PyCharmCE2020.1/scratches/scratch.py", line 5, in suma_lista
    if len(lista) == 1:
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison
```

**Respuesta**

Según lo veo, la única respuesta razonable es decirle:

1. Lo estas haciendo mal. Usa `sum` para sumar una lista.
2. No uses recursión para un proceso iterativo.
3. No acumules en una lista lo que puede ser calculado *in-line*.
4. Tu problema no es de memoria, es de método.

El algoritmo correcto es:

```
suma = 0
cta = 1000
for i in range(cta):
    suma += some_function(i)

promedio = suma / cta
```

[Por supuesto, además se le explica el porqué de cada cosa]

**Opinión**

Si el usuario no entiende donde está el problema, ni lo que está haciendo, y además lo está haciendo mal, no veo razón ni ventaja en limitarnos a las condiciones de su problema.

En este caso, la solución no contiene ni listas ni recursión ni habla sobre la memoria RAM, pero educa al usuario (y a otros como él) y resuelve su problema.

Al responder debemos plantearnos ¿qué es lo mejor para el bien común? ¿Satisfacer a los puristas o educar a esta pobre alma perdida?

Dejar preguntas sin responder simplemente porque el pobre usuario no sabe ni donde está parado no ayuda a nadie.

Responder puebla SOes. Cuando el sitio está poblado, aparece en Google. Cuando aparece en Google, atrae visitantes. Asi crece SOes y sus usuarios.

Cuando un alumno se equivoca, no lo castigas; lo educas mostrandole la manera correcta. Así corregirá su error y aprenderá para no repetirlo más adelante.

**Postdata**

Luego de publicar, me encontre con un caso real que ilustra lo señalado por OP [Cómo muestro secciones de una lista](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/372391/c%c3%b3mo-muestro-secciones-de-una-listapython).

La cosa parte así:

> No sé como hacer que se muestre por pantalla secciones de una lista(En
> este caso de hijos). Ya que por ejemplo a la familia A le
> corresponderían los hijos a, b,c y a la familia B los hijos d, e, f,
> g. Por lo que los hijos de familia A serían hasta hijos[2] y los
> siguientes de hijos[3] a hijos[5] y así sucesivamente para n familias
> y m hijos por familia.

Un pregunta que específicamente habla de listas.

La respuesta de @aeportugal comienza asi:

> Ni lista, ni tupla, son estructuras de datos adecuadas para lo que se
> solicita. Para estos casos, lo más cómodo sería usar diccionarios, los
> cuales se comportan como un json. Un ejemplo conceptual puede ser:

El código con que ilustra su respuesta no conserva nada del código aportado por el OP.

La respuesta, sin embargo, es correcta: resuelve el problema inmediato del OP, le enseña técnicas fundamentales y es de utilidad para visitantes posteriores.

Comment: Gran respuesta, estoy muy de acuerdo (lo de _enseñar a pescar y no dar peces_, etc)

Comment: Muy interesante y correcta tu respuesta @CandidMoe , te comentaré también que en ocasiones el OP al recibir este tipo de respuestas, entra a un mundo desconocido y tristemente no la ve como una respuesta que esperaba, pero sin duda como lo señalas le enseña y es de utilidad a otros miembros de la comunidad!.